# Красивый dropdown и не работающий submit

Tags: javascript, dropdown, submit

Имею следующий dropdown (demo прилагается). Помогите пожалуйста добавить в него `onchange="this.form.submit()"` чтобы он отрабатывался

Из-за скриптов, добавление в select этого куска кода, submit не отрабатывается. Сам select я выделил в форму:

```
<form action="/onchange1"  method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="onchang1" value="">
</form/
```

```js
/**
 * jquery.dropdown.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

 'use strict';

 $.DropDown = function( options, element ) {
  this.$el = $( element );
  this._init( options );
 };

 // the options
 $.DropDown.defaults = {
  speed : 300,
  easing : 'ease',
  gutter : 0,
  // initial stack effect
  stack : true,
  // delay between each option animation
  delay : 0,
  // random angle and positions for the options
  random : false,
  // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
  // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
  rotated : false,
  // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
  slidingIn : false
 };

 $.DropDown.prototype = {

  _init : function( options ) {

   // options
   this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DropDown.defaults, options );
   this._layout();
   this._initEvents();

  },
  _layout : function() {

   var self = this;
   this.minZIndex = 1000;
   this._transformSelect();
   this.opts = this.listopts.children( 'li' );
   this.optsCount = this.opts.length;
   this.size = { width : this.dd.width(), height : this.dd.height() };
   this.inputEl = $( '<input type="hidden" name="cd-dropdown"></input>' ).insertAfter( this.selectlabel );
   this.selectlabel.css( 'z-index', this.minZIndex + this.optsCount );
   this._positionOpts();
   if( Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
    setTimeout( function() { self.opts.css( 'transition', 'all ' + self.options.speed + 'ms ' + self.options.easing ); }, 25 );
   }

  },
  _transformSelect : function() {

   var optshtml = '', selectlabel = '';
   this.$el.children( 'option' ).each( function() {

    var $this = $( this ),
     val = isNaN( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ? $this.attr( 'value' ) : Number( $this.attr( 'value' ) ) ,
     classes = $this.attr( 'class' ),
     label = $this.text();

    val !== -1 ?
     classes !== undefined ?
      optshtml += '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>' :
      optshtml += '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span>' + label + '</span></li>' :
     selectlabel = label;

   } );

   this.listopts = $( '<ul/>' ).append( optshtml );
   this.selectlabel = $( '<span/>' ).append( selectlabel );
   this.dd = $( '<div class="cd-dropdown"/>' ).append( this.selectlabel, this.listopts ).insertAfter( this.$el );
   this.$el.remove();

  },
  _positionOpts : function( anim ) {

   var self = this;

   this.listopts.css( 'height', 'auto' );
   this.opts
    .each( function( i ) {
     $( this ).css( {
      zIndex : self.minZIndex + self.optsCount - 1 - i,
      top : self.options.slidingIn ? ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ) : 0,
      left : 0,
      marginLeft : self.options.slidingIn ? i % 2 === 0 ? self.options.slidingIn : - self.options.slidingIn : 0,
      opacity : self.options.slidingIn ? 0 : 1,
      transform : 'none'
     } );
    } );

   if( !this.options.slidingIn ) {
    this.opts
     .eq( this.optsCount - 1 )
     .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 9 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 4 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 8 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
     .end()
     .eq( this.optsCount - 2 )
     .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 6 : 0, left : this.options.stack ? 2 : 0, width : this.options.stack ? this.size.width - 4 : this.size.width, transform : 'none' } )
     .end()
     .eq( this.optsCount - 3 )
     .css( { top : this.options.stack ? 3 : 0, left : 0, transform : 'none' } );
   }

  },
  _throwHook : function( el, action, trigger ){
   var $el = $( el );
   var eventName = [ action, trigger, 'dropdown' ].join( '.' );
   var event = $.Event( eventName );
   event.value = $el.data( 'value' );
   $el.trigger( event );
  },
  _initEvents : function() {
   
   var self = this,
    throwHook = this._throwHook;
   
   this.selectlabel.on( 'mousedown.dropdown', function( event ) {
    self.opened ? self.close() : self.open();
    return false;

   } );

   this.opts.on( 'click.dropdown', function() {
    if( self.opened ) {
     var opt = $( this );
     opt.delegate( 'li', 'click.dropdown', throwHook( this, 'opened', 'click') );
     self.inputEl.val( opt.data( 'value' ) );
     self.selectlabel.html( opt.html() );
     self.close();
    }
   } );

        },

  open : function() {
   var self = this;
   this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
   this.listopts.css( 'height', ( this.optsCount + 1 ) * ( this.size.height + this.options.gutter ) );
   this.opts.each( function( i ) {

    $( this ).css( {
     opacity : 1,
     top : self.options.rotated ? self.size.height + self.options.gutter : ( i + 1 ) * ( self.size.height + self.options.gutter ),
     left : self.options.random ? Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) : 0,
     width : self.size.width,
     marginLeft : 0,
     transform : self.options.random ?
      'rotate(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 - 5 ) + 'deg)' :
      self.options.rotated ?
       self.options.rotated === 'right' ?
        'rotate(-' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)' :
        'rotate(' + ( i * 5 ) + 'deg)'
       : 'none',
     transitionDelay : self.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ? self.options.slidingIn ? ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : 0
    } );

   } );
   this.opened = true;

  },
  close : function() {

   var self = this;
   this.dd.toggleClass( 'cd-active' );
   if( this.options.delay && Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
    this.opts.each( function( i ) {
     $( this ).css( { 'transition-delay' : self.options.slidingIn ? ( ( self.optsCount - 1 - i ) * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' : ( i * self.options.delay ) + 'ms' } );
    } );
   }
   this._positionOpts( true );
   this.opened = false;

  }

 }

 $.fn.dropdown = function( options ) {
  var instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown' );
  if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
   this.each(function() {
    instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
   });
  }
  else {
   this.each(function() {
    instance ? instance._init() : instance = $.data( this, 'dropdown', new $.DropDown( options, this ) );
   });
  }
  return instance;
 };

} )( jQuery, window );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <title>Simple Effects for Drop-Down Lists</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Simple Effects for Drop-Down Lists" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="drop-down, select, jquery, plugin, fallback, transition, transform, 3d, css3" />
  <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/css/style5.css" />
  <script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container"> 
   <!-- Codrops top bar -->
   <div class="codrops-top clearfix">
    
    </span>
   </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->
      <form action="/onchange1"  method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="onchang1" value="">
   <section class="main clearfix">
    <div class="fleft">
     <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="-1" selected>Select a browser</option>
      <option value="1" class="icon-chrome">Chrome</option>
      <option value="2" class="icon-safari">Safari</option>
      <option value="3" class="icon-IE">Internet Explorer</option>
      <option value="4" class="icon-firefox">Firefox</option>
      <option value="5" class="icon-opera">Opera</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </section>
      </form>
  </div><!-- /container -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   $( function() {
    
    $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown( {
     gutter : 5,
     stack : false,
     slidingIn : 100
    } );

   });

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: плохо, что этот дропдаун убирает select, даже input, который содержит значение выбранного элемента имеет name отличный от того, что был у select - я бы не стал использовать этот dropdown. Либо допилить его хотябы чтобы он name использовал тот же и при смене делал trigger('change') тогда можно ловить событие снаружи

Comment: Проблема в том что если брать любой другой "красивый" dropdown - везде используются скрипты и как я понимаю из-за этого не отрабатывает submit

Comment: Дайте ссылку на документацию DropDown-a?

Comment: @Jamshed http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/2638-simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists.html

Comment: Добавил ответ, надеюсь поможет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Они добавили слушатель onOptionSelect.

Проставьте слушатель

```
onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
```

Оф. Репозиторий. 
https://github.com/codrops/SimpleDropDownEffects/blob/master/js/jquery.dropdown.js

Issue который в по которому был добавлен слушатель

https://github.com/codrops/SimpleDropDownEffects/issues/3

```
$.DropDown.defaults = {
        speed : 300,
        easing : 'ease',
        gutter : 0,
        // initial stack effect
        stack : true,
        // delay between each option animation
        delay : 0,
        // random angle and positions for the options
        random : false,
        // rotated [right||left||false] : the options will be rotated to thr right side or left side.
        // make sure to tune the transform origin in the stylesheet
        rotated : false,
        // effect to slide in the options. value is the margin to start with
        slidingIn : false,
        onOptionSelect : function(opt) { return false; }
    };
```

Comment: я добавил в скрипт недостающую строку, а в <select .... onchange="this.form.submit()"> - но это не помогло. Думаю я что-то не правильно делаю

Comment: Вам надо, скачать версию с github тогда это заработает!

Comment: скачал - не заработало... проще реально найти другой dropdown

Comment: не так <select .... onchange="this.form.submit()">. листнер надо ставить на onOptionSelect при конфигурировании.